# Запросы PUT/PATCH/DELETE

Tags: html, python, django, api, delete

Изучаю первый день Django. Создал html файл, связал его с представлениями через URL как показано тут: https://metanit.com/python/django/5.5.php. Тут реализовано удаление и изменение базы данных переходом по другому адресу и методом `POST`. Но не могу понять как реализовать это через методы `PUT/PATCH/DELETE`. Насколько я знаю html не поддерживает иных методов кроме `POST/GET`. 
Как можно это реализовать через django и html? 
***UPD:***
Реализовал ajax-запрос DELETE:

```
var token = '{{csrf_token}}';
$(function() {
        $("td").click(function(e) {
            var id = $("#"+e.target.id);
            $.ajax({
                headers: { "X-CSRFToken": token },
                url: "ally/"+id+"/",
                type: 'DELETE',

            });
        });
    });
```

В командной строке пишет `"DELETE ally/[object20Object]/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3726`, однако по какой-то причине в представлениях этот запрос функция не ловит.
from django.http import *

```
def edit(request):
       if request.method == "DELETE":
            return HttpResponse("<h1>ALLY<h1>")
```

Может кто знает в чем проблема?

Comment: В Django просто замените `"POST"` на `"PUT"` или `"PATCH"` или `"DELETE"`, а из браузера отправляйте соответствующий ajax-запрос без html-формы

Comment: Извините, не могли бы вы небольшой пример привести? Я ни в JS ни в Jquery не очень хорош. Или может есть какой-то иной способ?

Comment: @Denzel Сделай `console.log(id)`. Там у тебя объект, а не ID, поэтому дергается неверный URL.
И еще совет. Называй path в множественном числе, т.е. у тебя это будет *allies*. Подробнее тут.
[RestApi](https://habr.com/ru/post/351890/)

Comment: А зачем event вешать на ячейку таблицы? Если не секрет.

Comment: 1)console.log(id) пишет undefined. 2) Что за таблица? Вы имеете в виду ячейку памяти? Ps: сам не знаю, что точно делаю. Мне нужно передать запрос DELETE во views.py.

Comment: Заменил var id = $(e.target).attr("id"), теперь работает как надо.